# Is there a way to access Google My Business Data in BigQuery?

Tags: etl, data-integration, google-my-business-api

We are working on a project where we want to access all the information from our numerous Google My Business locations. We would like to access that GMB information with our Google Analytics data and have it automatically refresh for a dashboard. We have looked into using Super Metrics and loading the data in that way, but we want to avoid upgrading our Super Metrics account.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, what solution did/would you implement?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment paying supermetrics, but some alternatives we are looking at are Keboola, Dataddo or building into airbyte, may it will come soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two solutions here :

- Pay supermetrics or any self managed data loader (stitch, fivetran etc)
- Code your own ETL